# Merge CSV files in multiple sub directories using Cygwin

Tags: csv, cygwin

I'm new to Cygwin and could really use some help. I have a root directory with multiple sub directories (all sub directories are on the same level, that is no sub-sub directories etc). Each sub directory contains several CSV files (same format, no headers). I'd like to merge the CSVs in each sub directory into one large CSV file for each sub directory. That is, one CSV per sub directory, containing the contents of all CSVs in that individual sub directory.

I think I can use the simple command `cat *.csv > largefile.csv`, but I'm not so sure how to scan through all the sub directories and apply this code to each one. Based on the tutorials I've worked through, I believe this should work:

```
for dir in `find . -type d`
do cat *.csv > largefile.csv
done
```

Is this the best approach? It seems way too simple.

Also, is there a way to store these commands in a file that I could execute whenever I need to perform this task?

Thanks in advance for helping this beginner out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it by creating this file:

**cat_all_csv_dir.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in *; do
    # continue if it is not a directory or if it does not contain any csv
    if [ ! -d "$dir" ] || [ -z "$(ls "$dir"/*.csv 2>/dev/null)" ]; then
        continue;
    fi
    cat "$dir"/*.csv > "$dir".csv
    echo $dir
done
```

You should create it in a folder, which is present in `PATH` environment variable.
Its value could be printed by typing `echo $PATH` command. 
By this way `cat_all_csv_dir.sh` could be run from any directory.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I get the following error when I call the script from the directory containing my CSVs: `$ cat_all_csv_dir.sh
/usr/local/bin/cat_all_csv_dir.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'usr/local/bin/cat_all_csv_dir.sh: line 2: `for dir in *;do`  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "\r" is present in the error message. It means that you created the file with windows line endings. You should convert it to unix line endings. This could be done for example with Notepad++. (Edit menu -> EOL conversion -> UNIX/OSX format)

Comment: I really appreciate your reply, but I can't seem to get this to work. I changed the EOL to UNIX format and ran the script again from the directory containing the CSVs. Nothing seems to happen. No errors, but no new file created either. Cygwin seems to think for a moment or two, then gives me the prompt ($) on a new line. I can confirm that the .sh file is saved in a directory listed under $PATH. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: You're right. I edited the reply. `ls "$dir"/*.csv` should be written instead of `ls *.csv`.